# how to count how many returned values

Tags: python, list

my code is very bad but it is a simple project that I can make a lot better with tkinter, by the way i am not a new contibuter but im using my school laptop

```
ideas = []
function = input("Append or Search")
if function == "Append":
    ideas.append(input("what would you like to append enter keywords/possible names...")
if function == "Search":
    searcher = input("What would you like to search for, enter keywords/possible names")
    if searcher in ideas:
        numberOfResults = ?
        print(numberOfResults + "results found")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [the count function](https://www.guru99.com/python-list-count.html) to count the number of instances of an element in a list

```
ideas = []
function = input("Append or Search")
if function == "Append":
    ideas.append(input("what would you like to append enter keywords/possible names...")
if function == "Search":
    searcher = input("What would you like to search for, enter keywords/possible names")
    numberOfResults = ideas.count(searcher)
    print(numberOfResults + "results found")
```

Comment: Can possibly remove `if searcher in ideas` then. It needlessly iterates the list twice (once for the `in` check, second for `.count`). Just remove it and let it say `0 results found`. If OP wants a different behavior in that case, they can achieve that by checking `if numberOfResults == 0`

Comment: you're right, I've amended the code like you suggested